# Polymer get the value from a paper input element

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have just started exploring polymer.js. I want to get name from paper-input element. It isn't working the alert is empty.

```
<dom-module id="hello-world">
<template>
    <h1> Hello [[name]]</h1>
    <paper-input value="{{name}}"></paper-input>
    <button onClick="{{getData}}">Get data</button>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "hello-world",
        properties: {
            name: {
                type: String,
                value: '1'
            }
        },
        getData: function () {
            alert(this.name);
        }
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `onClick` event, use `on-click="getData"` in polymer template.

> ....To add event listeners to local DOM children, use on-event
>   annotations in your template. This often eliminates the need to give
>   an element an id solely for the purpose of binding an event listener.
>
> Because the event name is specified using an HTML attribute, the event
>   name is always converted to lowercase. This is because HTML attribute
>   names are case insensitive. So specifying on-myEvent adds a listener
>   for myevent. The event handler name (for example, handleClick) is case
>   sensitive. To avoid confusion, always use lowercase event names.

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/VXOgrj)